# How can I increase the time a Javascript drop-down menu remains on-screen?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there any way to increase the time a drop-down menu created stays on screen?  The drop down menu just appears and disappears as I touch the cursor.  The drop-down was created using Prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different drop down menu:

Here's over 25 that might better suit your needs:

- http://www.noupe.com/css/multilevel-drop-down-navigation-menus-examples-and-tutorials.html

Or mention what drop down menu you are using so we can at least discover the option for you!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever function you have attached to the rolloff of the menu to make it disappear, add that code to another function and use a setTimeout() call to pause for a time before removing the menu.

Example:

```
Old Code
var closeMenu = function() {
    $('menu').hide();
};

New Code
var hideMenu = function() {
    $('menu').hide();
};

var closeMenu = function() {
    setTimeout(hideMenu, 5000);
};
```

With that change, you've now delayed the menu's disappearing act for 5 seconds. Probably don't want to take that long but you get the idea.